# SQL_NO_CACHE does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

The first time I run this sql, needs 39 seconds,when I run again and increase SQL_NO_CACHE,does not seem to take effect:

```
mysql> select count(*) from `deal_expired` where `site`=8&&`area`=122 && 
endtime<1310444996056;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      497 |
+----------+
1 row in set (39.55 sec)

mysql> select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from `deal_expired` where `site`=8&&`area`=
122 && endtime<1310444996056;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      497 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

I tried a variety of methods,  [here](http://www.issociate.de/board/post/493985/SQL_NO_CACHE.html)

and even restart the mysql server or change table name, but I still can not let 39 seconds run this SQL

I replaced another SQL, and an increase in the first run on SQL_NO_CACHE, the problem is the same:

```
mysql> select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from `deal_expired` where `site`=25&&`area`=
134 && endtime<1310483196227;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      315 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.17 sec)

mysql> select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from `deal_expired` where `site`=25&&`area`=
134 && endtime<1310483196227;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      315 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

What is the reason?
How can I get the same SQL run-time?

I want to find a way to optimize this SQL to perform 39 seconds

BTW: `RESET QUERY CACHE` `FLUSH QUERY CACHE` `FLUSH TABLES` `SET SESSION query_cache_type=off` does not work

mysql state cache has been closed:

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE "Qcache%";
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 0     |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 0     |
| Qcache_hits             | 0     |
| Qcache_inserts          | 0     |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0     |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 0     |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 0     |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 0     |
+-------------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from `deal_expired` where `site`=25&&`area`=134 && endtime<1310
483196227;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      315 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE "Qcache%";
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 0     |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 0     |
| Qcache_hits             | 0     |
| Qcache_inserts          | 0     |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0     |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 0     |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 0     |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 0     |
+-------------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

explan this SQL,used site+endtime composite index(named site_endtime):

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from `deal_expired` where `site`=8&&`area`=122 && endti
me<1310444996056;
+--------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+------
-+------+-------------+
| table  | type | possible_keys                 | key          | key_len | ref
 | rows | Extra       |
+--------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+------
-+------+-------------+
| deal_expired | ref  | name,url,endtime,site_endtime | site_endtime |       4 | const
 |  353 | Using where |
+--------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+------
-+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you use **composite** index for this query?

Comment: @Karolis has a site+endtime (named `site_endtime`) composite index

Comment: I don't know anything about your particular database, but it seems that it would be a good idea to create another composite index (site+area+endtime). MySql will read less rows, so it should become faster.

Comment: @Karolis,thanks, I will create `expired` boolean field(0 and 1),and change my SQL query to: `site=?&&area=?&&expired=1` and create site+area+expired composite index, is this better than `site=?&&area=?&&endtime<now` + site+area+endtime composite index?

Comment: I think there should be no much difference between (site+area+endtime) and (site+area+expired). But you can test it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer to "How can I get the same SQL run-time?" is - you cannot. 
If your query reads some rows, they are cached, dependent on the storage engine in use, those rows are either in OS cache (myisam), or in buffer pool (innodb). If rows are cached, running the same query second time is much faster, because MySQL does not have to read from the disk.

Comment: That I have no way to optimize this to run 39 seconds sql?

Comment: @Zenofo, the only way to try to reproduce the "cold cache" run is to restart mysql.

Comment: Even restarting mysql might not cut it, if the index/data files are in the OS file/block cache.

Comment: Typically, "optimize" means run faster :) I do not seen many people asking for a way to run slower. If you're using MyISAM, you may be out of luck, but if with Innodb on Linux innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT should avoid caching in the filesystem.

Comment: On Linux, you can also do `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to clear the OS cache.

Comment: SQL_NO_CACHE to tell MySQL not to put the result into the cache. So you got expected results only if you use SQL_NO_CACHE since first execution of a specific query. So Mysql NEVER find results in cache

Comment: realtebo. It is not about whether MySQL find result in a specific "query cache". This is about this - there are so many caches on so many levels, that it is virtually impossible to tell mysql to run a query second time as slow as it was run first time.

Answer (score 46):

The first query should use SQL_NO_CACHE to tell MySQL not to put the **result** into the cache. The second query uses the cache and the tells MySQL not to cache the result of that query, which does nothing.

tl;dr - Reverse your queries.

Comment: I don't understand why this was not selected as correct answer. It should be.

Comment: According to [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html) `SQL_NO_CACHE` on second SELECT should skip checking query cache, so the above should not be needed:"The server does not use the query cache. It neither checks the query cache to see whether the result is already cached, nor does it cache the query result."

Comment: **This answer is not correct**, because a query with `SQL_NO_CACHE` can also never be served with a response from the query cache. The query cache is checked  *before* the SQL parser runs, using the *exact bytes* of the query for matching. Unless the response to a query made up of the exact same bytes is already in the cache, there's no possible result to use... and since the result from a query with `SQL_NO_CACHE` will never be written to the query cache, it can never be served from the cache. `SQL_NO_CACHE` is thus guaranteed to behave as OP expects, never serving a response from the cache.

Comment: It didn't work for me, the first query with SQL_NO_CACHE took 2 minutes, the second time also using SQL_NO_CACHE took 15 seconds

Answer (score 10):

I was under the impression that including any sort of SQL function that is calculated in the current runtime would not cache. Have you tried doing something like the following?

```
select count(*), now() from `deal_expired` where `site`=8&&`area`=122 && endtime<1310444996056;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. see: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,225286,225468#msg-225468
2. you could try `RESET QUERY CACHE` (you need the RELOAD privilege) although having just read the link above this will probably not work either :(

Comment: I tried, `RESET QUERY CACHE` and `FLUSH TABLES`, `SET SESSION query_cache_type=off;` does not work