# can this phpbb query be optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpbb

Here's some code adapted from phpBB.  Near as I can tell it's trying to delete all topics wherein the only poster is the target user.

(note that for testing purposes I changed the final query from a DELETE to a SELECT)

```
<?php
$user_id = 66275;

mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('db_name');

$start = microtime(true);
$total = 0;

define('POSTS_TABLE', 'phpbb_posts');
define('TOPICS_TABLE', 'phpbb_topics');

         $sql = 'SELECT topic_id, COUNT(post_id) AS total_posts 
            FROM ' . POSTS_TABLE . " 
            WHERE poster_id = $user_id 
            GROUP BY topic_id"; 
         $result = mysql_query($sql);

         $topic_id_ary = array(); 
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
         { 
            $topic_id_ary[$row['topic_id']] = $row['total_posts']; 
         } 
         mysql_free_result($result); 

         if (sizeof($topic_id_ary)) 
         { 
            $sql = 'SELECT topic_id, topic_replies, topic_replies_real 
               FROM ' . TOPICS_TABLE . ' 
               WHERE ' . sql_in_set('topic_id', array_keys($topic_id_ary)); 
            $result = mysql_query($sql); 

            $del_topic_ary = array(); 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            { 
               if (max($row['topic_replies'], $row['topic_replies_real']) + 1 == $topic_id_ary[$row['topic_id']]) 
               { 
                  $del_topic_ary[] = $row['topic_id']; 
               } 
            } 
            mysql_free_result($result); 

            if (sizeof($del_topic_ary)) 
            { 
               $sql = 'SELECT topic_id FROM ' . TOPICS_TABLE . ' 
                  WHERE ' . sql_in_set('topic_id', $del_topic_ary); 
               $result = mysql_query($sql);
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
               { 
$total++;
                  echo $row[topic_id] . "\r\n";
               } 
            } 
         }

    function sql_in_set($field, $array, $negate = false, $allow_empty_set = false)
    {
        if (!sizeof($array))
        {
            if (!$allow_empty_set)
            {
                // Print the backtrace to help identifying the location of the problematic code
                $this->sql_error('No values specified for SQL IN comparison');
            }
            else
            {
                // NOT IN () actually means everything so use a tautology
                if ($negate)
                {
                    return '1=1';
                }
                // IN () actually means nothing so use a contradiction
                else
                {
                    return '1=0';
                }
            }
        }

        if (!is_array($array))
        {
            $array = array($array);
        }

        if (sizeof($array) == 1)
        {
            @reset($array);
            $var = current($array);

            return $field . ($negate ? ' <> ' : ' = ') . $var;
        }
        else
        {
            return $field . ($negate ? ' NOT IN ' : ' IN ') . '(' . implode(', ', $array) . ')';
        }
    }



$elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;

echo "\r\ntook $elapsed seconds";
echo "\r\ngot $total rows back";
?>
```

This does three queries.  First gets all the topics the target user has posted in and the number of times they've posted in each topic. The second gets how many replies each topic in the first query actually has. Then there's some PHP code to see which topics have had all their posts made by the target user.  After that the code (prior to my changes) DELETEs all those topics.

Overall it seems to me that this could be written better by doing something like this:

```
SELECT t.topic_id 
FROM phpbb_topics AS t 
JOIN phpbb_posts AS p1
   ON p1.topic_id = t.topic_id
      AND p1.poster_id = $poster_id
LEFT JOIN phpbb_posts AS p2 
   ON p2.topic_id = t.topic_id 
      AND p2.poster_id <> $poster_id
WHERE p2.poster_id IS NULL;
```

Or maybe this:

```
SELECT t.topic_id 
FROM phpbb_topics AS t 
JOIN phpbb_posts AS p1
   ON p1.topic_id = t.topic_id
      AND p1.poster_id = $poster_id
      AND t.topic_poster = $poster_id
      AND t.topic_last_poster_id = $poster_id
LEFT JOIN phpbb_posts AS p2 
   ON p2.topic_id = t.topic_id 
      AND p2.poster_id <> $poster_id
WHERE p2.poster_id IS NULL
```

Testing this is actually quite difficult thanks to [MySQLs caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778781/sql-cache-interfering-with-my-attempts-to-do-query-optimization) but...  from what testing I have been able to do it seems like the way phpBB is currently doing it is in fact faster.  Which is surprising to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: The multiple joins will introduce a decent performance hit.  You'd probably be better off using a subselect and then you could focus on the posts table query.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are on the right track. Try adding indexes to all the columns you are using in the joins as this can often drastically increase the speed of joins.